# Password & ConfirmPassword Validation Android Not Working

Tags: android, android-intent

I have two pages .I am trying to pass `Password` field value through `Bundle` & Check this value with `ConfirmPassword` field . Validation not working .May I know what is the correct way to achieve my objective?Maybe this question too basic, but i did't find any suitable solution.Please Help me out.

Here is my code :

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_passcode);

        EditTextUserPass= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.UserHiddenPass);
        EditTextUserPass.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        Imagepassone = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ButtonPassOne);
        Imagepasstwo = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ButtonPassTwo);

        Imagepassone.setOnClickListener(imgButtonHandlerone); 
        Imagepasstwo.setOnClickListener(imgButtonHandlertwo); 


        image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imagefirstpasscode);
        image2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imagesecondpasscode);
        image3=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imagethirdpasscode);
        image4=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imagefourpasscode);

    }


    View.OnClickListener imgButtonHandlerone = new View.OnClickListener() {


        public void onClick(View v) { 

            if(v.getId() == R.id.ButtonPassOne) {

                nbStep++;

                changeStepBackground(nbStep);
            }
        }
   };
   public void changeStepBackground(int i) { 
        // four step switch
        switch(i) {
            case 1:
                image.setImageResource(R.drawable.passselect);
                EditTextUserPass.setText("1");

            break;
            case 2:
                image2.setImageResource(R.drawable.passselect);
                EditTextUserPass.setText("1");
            break;
            case 3:
                image3.setImageResource(R.drawable.passselect);
                EditTextUserPass.setText("1");
            break;
            case 4:
                image4.setImageResource(R.drawable.passselect);
                EditTextUserPass.setText("1");
            break;


        }
    }

   View.OnClickListener imgButtonHandlertwo = new View.OnClickListener() {



    public void onClick(View v) { 

           if(v.getId() == R.id.ButtonPassTwo) {

               nbStep++;

               changeStepBackground2(nbStep);
           }
       }
  };
  public void changeStepBackground2(int i) { 

        switch(i) {
            case 1:
                image.setImageResource(R.drawable.passselect);
                EditTextUserPass.setText("2");
            break;
            case 2:
                image2.setImageResource(R.drawable.passselect);
                EditTextUserPass.setText("2");
            break;
            case 3:
                image3.setImageResource(R.drawable.passselect);
                EditTextUserPass.setText("2");
            break;
            case 4:
                image4.setImageResource(R.drawable.passselect);
                EditTextUserPass.setText("2");
            break;


        }
    }

}
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
       moveTaskToBack(true); 
       UserPasscode.this.finish();
    }

    public void gotoconfirmpasscode(View v)

    {
        String UserPass=EditTextUserPass.getText().toString();  
        int numberOfImages=nbStep;
        if(numberOfImages!=4)
        {   
        }
        else
        { 

             Bundle b = new Bundle();
             b.putString("PASSWORD", UserPass);

        Intent intent = new Intent(UserPasscode.this,UserConfirmPasscode .class);
        intent.putExtras(b);
        startActivity(intent);
        }       

    }
}
```

2nd Page :

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_confirm_passcode);
        EditTextUserConfirmPass= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.UserHiddenConfirmPass);
        EditTextUserPass= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.UserHiddenPass);
        EditTextUserConfirmPass.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        UserHiddenConfirmPass2= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.UserHiddenConfirmPass2);
        UserHiddenConfirmPass2.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        Imagepassone = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ButtonPassOne);
        Imagepasstwo = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ButtonPassTwo);

        Imagepassone.setOnClickListener(imgButtonHandlerone); 
        Imagepasstwo.setOnClickListener(imgButtonHandlertwo); 


        image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imagefirstpasscode);
        image2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imagesecondpasscode);
        image3=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imagethirdpasscode);
        image4=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imagefourpasscode);
    }

View.OnClickListener imgButtonHandlerone = new View.OnClickListener() {


        public void onClick(View v) { 

            if(v.getId() == R.id.ButtonPassOne) {

                nbStep++;

                changeStepBackground(nbStep);
            }
        }
   };
   public void changeStepBackground(int i) { 
        // four step switch
        switch(i) {
            case 1:
                image.setImageResource(R.drawable.passselect);
                EditTextUserConfirmPass.setText("1");
            break;
            case 2:
                image2.setImageResource(R.drawable.passselect);
                EditTextUserConfirmPass.setText("1");
            break;
            case 3:
                image3.setImageResource(R.drawable.passselect);
                EditTextUserConfirmPass.setText("1");
            break;
            case 4:
                image4.setImageResource(R.drawable.passselect);
                EditTextUserConfirmPass.setText("1");
            break;


        }
    }

   View.OnClickListener imgButtonHandlertwo = new View.OnClickListener() {



    public void onClick(View v) { 

           if(v.getId() == R.id.ButtonPassTwo) {

               nbStep++;

               changeStepBackground2(nbStep);
           }
       }
  };
  public void changeStepBackground2(int i) { 

        switch(i) {
            case 1:
                image.setImageResource(R.drawable.passselect);
                EditTextUserConfirmPass.setText("2");
            break;
            case 2:
                image2.setImageResource(R.drawable.passselect);
                EditTextUserConfirmPass.setText("2");
            break;
            case 3:
                image3.setImageResource(R.drawable.passselect);
                EditTextUserConfirmPass.setText("2");
            break;
            case 4:
                image4.setImageResource(R.drawable.passselect);
                EditTextUserConfirmPass.setText("2");
            break;


        }
    }
                                        }

    public void gotoMain(View v)
    {
        Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
        String venName = b.getString("PASSWORD"); 
        UserHiddenConfirmPass2.setText(venName);

        Bundle c = new Bundle();
        String UserPass=c.getString("CONFIRMPASSWORD");
        EditTextUserConfirmPass.setText(UserPass);

        c.putString("CONFIRMPASSWORD", EditTextUserConfirmPass.getText().toString());

        int numberOfImages=nbStep;
        if(numberOfImages!=4 )
        {   
        }

        if(!venName.equals(UserPass)){

        }

        else{

        Intent intent = new Intent(this,MainActivity .class);
        startActivity(intent);  
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

String comparison is wrong. Always compare String with `.equals()` method.
Change this:

```
if(venName!=UserPass)
```

to this:

```
System.out.println("venName :: "+venName);
System.out.println("UserPass :: "+UserPass);
if(!venName.equals(UserPass))
```

Comment: i used if(!venName.equals(UserPass)){ } But hopeless

Comment: Put a log and check values of both String variable. And post logcat snapshot with values in above question.

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace `if(venName!=UserPass)` by if`(!venName.equals(UserPass))`.
This is the correct way to compare Strings.

Answer (score 1):

The **`==`** operator is used when we have to compare the String object references. If two String variables point to the same object in memory, the comparison returns true.

The [equals](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) method is used when we need to compare the content of the text present in the [String](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html) objects. This method returns true when two [String](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html) objects hold the same content (i.e. the same values).

**To compare two strings for equality, use equals( ).** It has this general form:

```
boolean equals(Object str)
```

Here, *str* is the String object being compared with the invoking String object. It returns true if the strings contain the same characters in the same order, and false otherwise.

Logic Courtesy

> https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Object.html

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try with 2 password field in single activty.?

like bellow

#### login.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtpwd"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:hint="Password" />
    
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/confpwd"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:hint="Confirm Password" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_login"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Login" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and now in your

#### example.java

```
TextView txtPwd = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtpwd);
        
        TextView txtConfPwd = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.confpwd);
        
        final String strPwd = txtPwd.getText().toString();
        final String strConfPwd = txtConfPwd.getText().toString();
        
        Button loginbtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_login);
        
        loginbtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (strPwd.equals(strConfPwd)) {
                    //password and confirm passwords equal.go to next step
                } else {
                    //passwords not matching.please try again
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: This answer is not related of mine question